# Symbolicate crash file with dSYM and .ipa file

Tags: xcode, crash, symbolicate

Is there any concreate way to symbolicate crash logs from my app, i have following things

- dSYM file
- .ipa Application file
- myapp.crash

  -
- I have tried symbolicatecrash script but it does not work somehow
- Xcode does not work also i have Xcode 4.3
- I even tried system 'atos' command but it gives me some c or c++ file

I dont have build file in my archive is it because of that, because app was build in different machine ?

Answer (score 6):

This may be too late.. but i saw the method in another link that i am now trying to find :P

- Rename your .ipa file to .zip
- Open the zip file to extract the app
- now run symbolicatecrash script or delete the .symbolicated folder
- and restart xcode

if not helpful to you, hope this helps others.

Edit: found the place [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Answer (score 3):

Aside from xcode's tools, you can use atos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/312725

Be sure to take slide into account as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576028/312725